# what type of "assert" should I use in rspec to validate pre-conditions are ok?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm using rspec with ruby on rails for testing.

Question - In a spec if I was to do a cross check a pre-condition is established properly before starting the test, what approach is recommended?

For example, using an rspec ".should" type assertion doesn't seem like this would be the right thing as I'm only checking a precondition...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A should is perfectly valid in this situation as it is a condition that should be valid at the start of the test.  As a very trivial example:

```
it "should increment by one" do
  value = 10
  value.should eql(10)
  value += 1
  value.should eql(11)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I would have two different tests: one asserting that things like your precondition can be set correctly, the other assuming it works and then testing whatever depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think current RSpec has that kind of feature, **it would be nice** to have some other method for these pre-condition assertions such as

```
it "should increment by one" do
  value = 10
  value.must eql(10) # This is a necessary pre-condition, not the actual test
  value += 1
  value.should eql(11)
end
```

But I guess there is no such method to distinguish things, but the [rspec-given](http://github.com/jimweirich/rspec-given) gem might be of interest.